# Postgres - calculate total working hours based on IN and OUT entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the below tables:

*1) My Company table*

```
 id |   c_name   |  c_code  | status 
----+------------+----------+--------
  1 | AAAAAAAAAA |  AA1234  | Active
```

2) My User table

```
 id |    c_id    | u_name   | status | emp_id 
----+------------+----------+--------+--------
  1 |      1     | XXXXXXXX | Active |    1   
  2 |      1     | YYYYYYYY | Active |    2
```

*3) My Attendance table*

```
 id |  u_id  |        swipe_time      | status 
----+--------+------------------------+--------
  1 |   1    |  2020-08-20 16:00:00   | IN     
  2 |   1    |  2020-08-20 20:00:00   | OUT    
  3 |   1    |  2020-08-20 21:00:00   | IN     
  4 |   1    |  2020-08-21 01:00:00   | OUT    
  5 |   1    |  2020-08-21 16:00:00   | IN     
  6 |   1    |  2020-08-21 19:00:00   | OUT
```

I need to calculate the attendance grouped by date, u_id like below:

Note: The query parameters would be the "From Date", "To Date" and "Company ID"

```
u_id |   u_name  |     date    |        in_time       |        out_time      | hrs 
-----+-----------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+-----
 1   |  XXXXXXXX | 2020-08-20  |  2020-08-20 16:00:00 |  2020-08-21 01:00:00 |  7  
 1   |  XXXXXXXX | 2020-08-21  |  2020-08-21 16:00:00 |  2020-08-21 19:00:00 |  4  
 2   |  YYYYYYYY |     null    |        null          |        null          |  0
```

Is this possible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: SQL Solution @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Thank you for the code. Yes @a_horse_with_no_name, its more challenging. Here, I want to list all the users in the same company with null values as given in the last table. How do we do that?

Comment: Do you have a layer where you have access to a complied or interpreted language before the data reaches it's destination.

If yes do it there. 

1. Lot easier to handle logic. 
2. way way easier to debug if things go wrong.
3. Can unit test if required


personally I keep the Extraction logic in sql minimalistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is to expand one row that covers two (calendar) days to two rows and allocating the hours of the "next" day correctly.

The first part is to get a pivot table that combines IN/OUT pairs into a single row.

A simple (yet not very efficient) approach is:

```
  select ain.u_id, 
         ain.swipe_time as time_in,
         (select min(aout.swipe_time)
          from attendance aout
          where aout.u_id = ain.u_id
            and aout.status = 'OUT'
            and aout.swipe_time > ain.swipe_time) as time_out
  from attendance ain
  where ain.status = 'IN'
```

The next step is to break up the rows with more than one day into two rows.

This assumes that you never have an IN/OUT pair that covers more than two days!

```
with inout as (
  select ain.u_id, 
         ain.swipe_time as time_in,
         (select min(aout.swipe_time)
          from attendance aout
          where aout.u_id = ain.u_id
            and aout.status = 'OUT'
            and aout.swipe_time > ain.swipe_time) as time_out
  from attendance ain
  where ain.status = 'IN'
), expanded as (
  select u_id, 
         time_in::date as "date", 
         time_in,
         time_out
  from inout     
  where time_in::date = time_out::date  
  union all
  select i.u_id, 
         x.time_in::date as date, 
         x.time_in,
         x.time_out
  from inout i   
    cross join lateral (
       select i.u_id, 
              i.time_in, 
              i.time_in::date + 1 as time_out
       union all
       select i.u_id, 
              i.time_out::date, 
              i.time_out
    ) x
  where i.time_out::date > i.time_in::date  
)
select *
from expanded;
```

The above returns the following for your sample data:

```
u_id | date       | time_in             | time_out           
-----+------------+---------------------+--------------------
   1 | 2020-08-20 | 2020-08-20 16:00:00 | 2020-08-20 20:00:00
   1 | 2020-08-20 | 2020-08-20 21:00:00 | 2020-08-21 00:00:00
   1 | 2020-08-21 | 2020-08-21 00:00:00 | 2020-08-21 01:00:00
   1 | 2020-08-21 | 2020-08-21 16:00:00 | 2020-08-21 19:00:00
```

How does this work?

So we first select all those rows that start and end on the same day with this part:

```
  select u_id, 
         time_in::date as "date", 
         time_in,
         time_out
  from inout     
  where time_in::date = time_out::date
```

The second part of the union splits up the rows that span two days by using a cross join that generates one row with the original start time and midnight, and another from midnight to the original end time:

```
  select i.u_id, 
         x.time_in::date as date, 
         x.time_in,
         x.time_out
  from inout i   
    cross join lateral (
       -- this generates a row for the first of the two days
       select i.u_id, 
              i.time_in, 
              i.time_in::date + 1 as time_out
       union all
       -- this generates the row for the next day
       select i.u_id, 
              i.time_out::date, 
              i.time_out
    ) x
  where i.time_out::date > i.time_in::date
```

At the end the new "expanded" rows are then aggregated by grouping them by user and date and left joined to the `users` table to get the username as well.

```sql
with inout as (
  select ain.u_id, 
         ain.swipe_time as time_in,
         (select min(aout.swipe_time)
          from attendance aout
          where aout.u_id = ain.u_id
            and aout.status = 'OUT'
            and aout.swipe_time > ain.swipe_time) as time_out
  from attendance ain
  where ain.status = 'IN'
), expanded as (
  select u_id, 
         time_in::date as "date", 
         time_in,
         time_out
  from inout     
  where time_in::date = time_out::date  
  union all
  select i.u_id, 
         x.time_in::date as date, 
         x.time_in,
         x.time_out
  from inout i   
    cross join lateral (
       select i.u_id, 
              i.time_in, 
              i.time_in::date + 1 as time_out
       union all
       select i.u_id, 
              i.time_out::date, 
              i.time_out
    ) x
  where i.time_out::date > i.time_in::date  
)
select u.id,
       u.u_name,
       e."date", 
       min(e.time_in) as time_in,
       max(e.time_out) as time_out,
       sum(e.time_out - e.time_in) as duration
from users u
  left join expanded e on u.id = e.u_id
group by u.id, u.u_name, e."date"
order by u.id, e."date";
```

Which then results in:

```
u_id | date       | time_in             | time_out            | duration                                     
-----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------
   1 | 2020-08-20 | 2020-08-20 16:00:00 | 2020-08-21 00:00:00 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 7 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs
   1 | 2020-08-21 | 2020-08-21 00:00:00 | 2020-08-21 19:00:00 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 4 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs
```

The "duration" column is an [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) which you can [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to your liking.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=acb730c51c2a827a81a2055d83927d3a)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort to provide the detailed answer. I am trying to understand it now and will use it.

Comment: It works perfectly when 'IN' and 'OUT' records are correct. But, I am facing an issue if the user missed one "OUT". Please help me on this. 
For example, 
(1, 1, '2020-08-20 16:00:00', 'IN'),
(2, 1, '2020-08-20 17:10:00', 'IN'),
(3, 1, '2020-08-20 20:00:00', 'OUT');

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name@, Could you check above case and help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Using [lead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) window function makes it somewhat simpler and readable. For balanced IN and OUT attendance events this will work fine, otherwise there will be null values for the attendance hours. This makes sense, because either the person has not left yet or has not attended yet or attendance data is corrupt.

```sql
select 
 u.id u_id, u.u_name,
 t.date_in date, t.t_in in_time, t.t_out out_time,
 extract('hour' from t.t_out - t.t_in) hrs
from users u
left outer join 
(
  select u_id,
  date_trunc('day', swipe_time) date_in,
  swipe_time t_in, 
  lead(swipe_time, 1) over (partition by u_id order by u_id, swipe_time) t_out,
  status
  from attendance
) t 
on u.id = t.u_id
where t.status = 'IN';
```